# Sublime Text 2 : "Find in Folder functionality" broken when working with samba reader

Tags: sublimetext2, samba

I am working Sublime Text 2 for PHP web development on a windows workstation where I use Sublime Text 2. Files are synchronised with a linux remote server thanks to a samba share.
I am encountering a problem with the "Find in Folder" functionality which  doesn't work with my project that is synchronized with the samba share.

I proceed as follow  : 
File > open Folder > enter \myserver\sambashare\www

Sublime Text  opens the folder without problem and I can edit my files and synchronize them with the server.

I then try to perform a search on the folder : right click > Find in Folder > type the search string
Sublime text returns no results (whereas it should have thousand results).

How can I fix this ? Does anybody encounter this problem when working with samba? The search works with local folders.

Comment: Not enough information.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the problem. This does not come from Sublime Text.
The search works but is very very slow. This is due to samba share performances, when I search in a large folder a string. the samba process consume a lot CPU and distant server performances decrease.

I will try a another way of synchronising files between linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have read I guess you synchronize them manually?

If you need to keep two projects synchronized and you can change to FTP, this plugin

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp

is great. It keeps your local folder synchronized with your remote Server automatically if correctly configured.